# Thinking Sphinx Rebuild, then whenever saving any page it does save, but return error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I did a `rake thinking_sphinx:rebuild`, then when I try to update any page/entry, it **does** save but it returns error. New data is saved, but the page returns error. What have I done wrong?

Before I did the above command, things were working fine. I had to issue that command because I did some changes on the sorting filter.

Comment: It would be great to see the error stacktrace, so we can figure out the cause. I've not seen ts:rebuild cause these problems before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out it was permission problem due to different ownership. Resolved with the methods mentioned by Pat over [here](http://osdir.com/ml/thinking-sphinx/2010-01/msg00012.html).

Thanks Pat!